# How do I find the maximum row count after returning the results of a SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query:

`SELECT * FROM Files WHERE FolderPath LIKE '%.SLDDRW' OR FolderPath LIKE '%.PDF'`

And it's returning 82,614 rows (I know this because SSMS tells me it in the bottom corner, but I don't know how to turn that into a variable), and what I ultimately want to do is compare the file name from `.foo` against `.bar` and if the PDF has a string in it that says "REV A" or "REV B" I want to then update another table with a matching file ID as to what the revision is.

An example of this would be:

If it's finding `UniqueFileName1.SLDDRW`, and finding `UniqueFileName1 REV A.PDF` in the same folder, I then want to update another table updating the REV value with whatever it finds there.

I'm new to SQL, so I'm not exactly sure how to pull data from the results of a query, but my game plan is to do a `While` loop to do the comparison and update, but I need the maximum returned results from the first query to make sure the while loop terminates. Right?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, this is the solution: `DECLARE @MaxRowCount INTEGER = @@RowCount`

Comment: Make sure to do that in the statement **IMMEDIATELY** afterwards. This won't work if there is another statement in between, even a `SET` or `IF`

Comment: @Charlieface oh! Thank you, I'll make sure to do that.

Comment: @Charlieface what happens if it's not immediately afterwards?

Comment: Then you get 1 or something else. It returns the result only of the immediately previous statement, so a `SET` or an `IF` have rowcount of 1